# como evitar doble visualización al rotar un div?

Tags: html5, css3

tengo un menu que rota las secciones para que el usuario tenga una breve reseña de lo que encontrara si ingresa a esa pagina. Hasta ahí todo bien. El problema se presenta (en algunos navegadores) cuando vuelve al estado original porque se visualizan ambas caras (frente y dorso) cuando uno saca el ratón de encima y se ve horrible. Hay alguna forma de corregir esto? Paso el código para que vean lo que tengo. Gracias

```css
.cajaMenu {
  width: 49%;
  height: 230px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #808080;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 1000px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.cajaMenu:hover .botonMenu {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.botonMenu {
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 1.2s linear;
  width: 100%;
}


/*--texto frente--*/

.frente {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.cajaMenu .botonMenu .frente h2 {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'EncodeThin';
  font-size: 1.2em;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*--icono seccion frente--*/

.cajaMenu .botonMenu .frente h2:before {
  font-family: 'icomoon';
  font-size: 4rem;
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.cajaMenu .botonMenu .frente h2#hacemos:before {
  content: '\e915';
}

.cajaMenu .botonMenu .frente h2#adaptable:before {
  content: '\e900';
}


/*--revez de cada seccion--*/

.cajaMenu .botonMenu .revez {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  font-size: .65em;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #f4f4f4;
}

.cajaMenu .botonMenu .revez a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: justify;
  hyphens: auto;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1.4em;
}


/*--titulo revez del div--*/

.cajaMenu .botonMenu .revez h3 {
  padding: 3px 0;
}


/*--texto revez del div--*/

.cajaMenu .botonMenu .revez p {
  padding: 3px 0;
}


/*--boton "ver mas" revez del div--*/

.cajaMenu .botonMenu .revez h4 {
  color: #fb700d;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15px;
  right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<nav id="seccion">
  <div class="cajaMenu">
    <div class="botonMenu">
      <div class="frente">
        <h2 id="hacemos"></h2>
        <h2>Que hacemos?</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="frente revez" id='meta'>
        <a href="nuestra_meta.php">
          <h3>No sabes por donde empezar...</h3>
          <p>Tranquilo! Junto a TIMON DIGITAL vas a lograr adaptarte al mundo de hoy de una manera sencilla. Conectarte con tus clientes, y brindales lo que necesitan desde donde sea que se encuentren.</p>

          <h4>Ver más +</h4>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cajaMenu">
    <div class="botonMenu">
      <div class="frente">
        <h2 id="adaptable"></h2>
        <h2>Diseños adaptables</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="introMenu frente revez" id='responsive'>
        <a href="diseno_responsive.php">
          <h3>Nuevas formas de conectarse...</h3>
          <p>Los teléfonos son una extensión de nosotros, y tu negocio no puede quedar afuera.</p>
          <p>TIMON DIGITAL crea tu web adaptable a todos los formatos de pantalla. Para que tus clientes puedan sacar el máximo partido de tu negocio.</p>
          <h4>Ver más +</h4>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Actualizado**

He actualizado la respuesta según me ha comentado el compañero @blonfu que no se veía bien en `Firefox` pero si en `Chrome`.

El problema venia de las alturas que se daba al elemento `.frente`: `height: 100%` la cual se perdía a darse la vuelta a su estado inicial.

Cambiando esa altura a la altura del padre `.cajaMenu` (230px) se ve ahora correctamente en los navegadores Chrome, FireFox y Safari, así preservando lo propiedad del `backface-visibility: hidden`.

```css
.cajaMenu {
  width: 49%;
  height: 230px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #808080;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 1000px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.cajaMenu:hover .botonMenu {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  /*
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  */
}

.botonMenu {
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 1.2s linear;
  width: 100%;
}


/*--texto frente--*/

.frente {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 230px; /* !!!!! Aquí estaba el error */
}

.cajaMenu .botonMenu .frente h2 {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'EncodeThin';
  font-size: 1.2em;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*--icono seccion frente--*/

.cajaMenu .botonMenu .frente h2:before {
  font-family: 'icomoon';
  font-size: 4rem;  
  /* Aquí hay problema con el navegador Safari
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  */
  font-weight: normal;
}

.cajaMenu .botonMenu .frente h2#hacemos:before {
  content: 'icon 1';
}

.cajaMenu .botonMenu .frente h2#adaptable:before {
  content: 'icon 2';
}


/*--revez de cada seccion--*/

.cajaMenu .botonMenu .revez {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  font-size: .65em;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #f4f4f4;
}

.cajaMenu .botonMenu .revez a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: justify;
  hyphens: auto;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1.4em;
}


/*--titulo revez del div--*/

.cajaMenu .botonMenu .revez h3 {
  padding: 3px 0;
}


/*--texto revez del div--*/

.cajaMenu .botonMenu .revez p {
  padding: 3px 0;
}


/*--boton "ver mas" revez del div--*/

.cajaMenu .botonMenu .revez h4 {
  color: #fb700d;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15px;
  right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<nav id="seccion">
  <div class="cajaMenu">
    <div class="botonMenu">
      <div class="frente">
        <h2 id="hacemos"></h2>
        <h2>Que hacemos?</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="frente revez" id='meta'>
        <a href="nuestra_meta.php">
          <h3>No sabes por donde empezar...</h3>
          <p>Tranquilo! Junto a TIMON DIGITAL vas a lograr adaptarte al mundo de hoy de una manera sencilla. Conectarte con tus clientes, y brindales lo que necesitan desde donde sea que se encuentren.</p>

          <h4>Ver más +</h4>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cajaMenu">
    <div class="botonMenu">
      <div class="frente">
        <h2 id="adaptable"></h2>
        <h2>Diseños adaptables</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="introMenu frente revez" id='responsive'>
        <a href="diseno_responsive.php">
          <h3>Nuevas formas de conectarse...</h3>
          <p>Los teléfonos son una extensión de nosotros, y tu negocio no puede quedar afuera.</p>
          <p>TIMON DIGITAL crea tu web adaptable a todos los formatos de pantalla. Para que tus clientes puedan sacar el máximo partido de tu negocio.</p>
          <h4>Ver más +</h4>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: buenisimo! mañana lo pruebo y te cuento como  me fue, muchas gracias